# Is C#'s null-conditional delegate invocation thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is how I have always written event raisers; for example PropertyChanged:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

In the latest Visual Studio, however, the light bulb thingamabob suggested simplifying the code to this:

```
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
```

Although I'm always in favor of simplification, I wanted to be sure this was safe.  In my original code, I assign the handler to a variable to prevent a race condition in which the subscriber could become disposed in between the null check and the invocation.  It seems to me that the new simplified form would suffer this condition, but I wanted to see if anyone could confirm or deny this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from MSDN:

> The new way is thread-safe because the compiler generates code to
>   evaluate PropertyChanged one time only, keeping the result in
>   temporary variable. You need to explicitly call the Invoke method
>   because there is no null-conditional delegate invocation syntax
>   PropertyChanged?(e). There were too many ambiguous parsing situations
>   to allow it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 7):

It is as thread-safe as the code it replaced (your first example) because it is doing the exact same thing, just using a hidden variable.

Answer (score 0):

Internally .net framework uses interlock.CompareExchange when you subscribe for an event. This means you already has memory barrier there. To be thread safe you need to use Volatile.Read when accessing your event handler (it applies implicit aquire memory barrier)

Volatile.Read(ref PropertyChanged)?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))

Source: [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454)

Other source: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/